# Create multiple SUM columns with data from a date range, where one column combines data from a joined third table

Tags: sql, presto

I’m creating a query that is grouping by an 'entity' column and also is outputing 4 new columns.

- These new columns sum or subtract amount values from an 'amount' column for each 'entity' based on a date range.
- I'm also trying to join a 3rd table (previous_year_table) and include data from it.

**Any guidance on how to make the below query possible? or guidance on a more efficient query(s)?**

The actual query I'm building is in the second code block.

```
SELECT
    ent.entity,
    SUM(data.amount) curr_month /* when data.ds between 1st of current month AND current date)*/
    SUM(data.amount) prev_month /* when data.ds between 1st of previous month AND current date)*/
    (SUBTRACT prev_month sum from curr_month sum) movement,
    (
      SUM(prev_data.amount) /* when prev_data.ds between 1st day of Previous year AND current date)*/
      + SUM(data.amount) /* when data.ds between 1st day of Current year AND current date)*/
    ) previous_year
FROM entity_table ent
JOIN current_year_table data
    ON data.unit = ent.unit
JOIN previous_year_table prev_data
    ON prev_data.unit = ent.unit
GROUP BY
    entity;
```

#### My current implementation of the above query

This is without the 'previous_year_table' join and seems to work so far but feels hacky.
Also I'm using prestodb syntax e.g. `DATE_TRUNC`, `current_date` etc

```
SELECT
    ent.entity,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN data.ds BETWEEN CAST(DATE_TRUNC('month', current_date) AS VARCHAR)
                AND CAST(current_date AS VARCHAR) THEN data.amount_usd
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) curr_month,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN data.ds BETWEEN CAST(
                (DATE_TRUNC('month', current_date) - INTERVAL '1' MONTH) AS VARCHAR
            ) AND CAST(current_date AS VARCHAR) THEN data.amount_usd
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) prev_month,
    (
        SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN data.ds BETWEEN CAST(DATE_TRUNC('month', current_date) AS VARCHAR)
                    AND CAST(current_date AS VARCHAR) THEN data.amount_usd
                ELSE 0
            END
        ) - SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN data.ds BETWEEN CAST(
                    (DATE_TRUNC('month', current_date) - INTERVAL '1' MONTH) AS VARCHAR
                ) AND CAST(current_date AS VARCHAR) THEN data.amount_usd
                ELSE 0
            END
        )
    ) movement
FROM entity_table ent
JOIN current_year_table data
    ON data.operating_unit = ent.operating_unit
GROUP BY
    entity;
```

#### Desired Query Output

| entity | current_month | previous_month | movement(curr - prev) | previous_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| entity_1 | 20 | 40 | -20 | 70 |
| entity_2 | 10 | 50 | -40 | 90 |

#### Query Input Tables

One to 'many' relationship between Entity_Table unit column and ####_Year_Table unit columns

**Entity_Table**

| entity | unit (join col) |
| --- | --- |
| entity_1 | 1 |
| entity_2 | 2 |

**Current_Year_Table**

| unit (join col) | amount | ds (datestamp string, curr year) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 2022-05-21 |
| 1 | 20 | 2022-04-19 |
| 2 | 10 | 2022-05-20 |
| 2 | 40 | 2022-04-26 |

**Previous_Year_Table**

| unit (join col) | amount | ds (datestamp string, prev year) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 2021-08-29 |
| 2 | 30 | 2021-03-18 |
| 2 | 10 | 2021-01-21 |
| 1 | 10 | 2021-02-13 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite strange formula for `movement` cause from this two :

> curr_month /* when data.ds between 1st of current month AND current date)*/
>
> prev_month /* when data.ds between 1st of previous month AND current date)*/

`movement` will always be just some for the previous month (between 1st and last day of month) taken with negative sign.

Also based on data it seems that for `previous_year` you actually want sum of current and previous years.

Other than that your approach is fine, I would suggest just small tweaks using [`if`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#if)'s, subselect and using data functions to make it more readable:

```sql
--sample data
WITH entity_table  (entity, operating_unit) AS (
    VALUES  ('entity_1', 1),
    ('entity_2', 2)
),
current_year_table (operating_unit, amount_usd, ds) AS (
    VALUES  
(1, 20, '2022-05-21'),
(1, 20, '2022-04-19'),
(2, 10, '2022-05-20'),
(2, 40, '2022-04-26')
),
previous_year_table (operating_unit, amount_usd, ds) AS (
    VALUES  
(1, 20, '2021-08-29'),
(2, 30, '2021-03-18'),
(2, 10, '2021-01-21'),
(1, 10, '2021-02-13')
)
```

Query:

```sql
-- query
select entity,
    curr_month,
    prev_month,
    curr_month - prev_month as movement,
    total_current_year + previous_year as previous_year
from (
        select ent.entity,
            ent.operating_unit,
            sum(
                if(
                    DATE_TRUNC('month', date(data.ds)) = DATE_TRUNC('month', now()),
                    amount_usd,
                    0
                )
            ) curr_month,
            sum(
                if(
                    // use = instead of >= if you want actual diff between current and previous month
                    DATE_TRUNC('month', date(data.ds)) >= DATE_TRUNC('month', now()) - interval '1' month,
                    amount_usd,
                    0
                )
            ) prev_month,
            sum(amount_usd) total_current_year
        FROM entity_table ent
            JOIN current_year_table data ON data.operating_unit = ent.operating_unit
        GROUP BY entity,
            ent.operating_unit
    ) as current_year_data
    join (
        select operating_unit,
            sum(amount_usd) as previous_year
        from previous_year_table
        group by operating_unit
    ) previous_year_data on current_year_data.operating_unit = previous_year_data.operating_unit
```

Output:

| entity | curr_month | prev_month | movement | previous_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| entity_1 | 20 | 40 | -20 | 70 |
| entity_2 | 10 | 50 | -40 | 90 |

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide this response. I'm currently breaking your solution down to make sure I understand it and testing the query.

Comment: It looks like your solution is meeting my use case, thanks so much! And yeah the 'movement' formula is interesting. I did notice the previous months amount data should always be larger, since it's the prev and curr months combined, so the movement will always be negative. I'll need to verify this requirement.